# how to remove values from signed out attribute in documentum

Tags: java, documentum, documentum6.5

when check out done in documentum. how to remove values of "Signed Out To" attribute in documentum using java dfc api. when sysobj.cancelcheckout executed only unlock function done and removes the lock icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock owner attribute (Signed out to) indicates who owns the lock. It also controls who can unlock it. So, you need to really think about what you are trying to achieve by getting rid of the lock owner name.